# EF Repository - Custom Remove Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, repository

I've created a generic EF repository. For every deletions I need to check if my entity has a specific interface and do some changes to some other entities before remove it. How would I do that?

I tried to crate a foreach like this but it's not working.

```
var entitiesToRemove = context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToList();

foreach (var entityToRemove in entitiesToRemove)
{
    ///
}
```

My current remove method

```
public void Remove(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    context.Set<TEntity>()
        .Where(predicate).ToList()
        .ForEach(del => context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(del));
}
```

Comment: Make the `Remove` method generic so it can only be called if the item has the specific interface.

Comment: Do you have an abstract base repository class and concrete repository implementations for every entity? Or is it just one repository class that will handle ALL entity types?

Comment: @Andrés Robinet it is just one repository class that handle all entity type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can tackle the problem via the `Strategy` pattern

What follows is *just one possible approach* and example. You'd have to take *dependency injection* into consideration as well (but you can adapt this idea)

```
/* Your Repository implementation would probably look like this */

public class GenericRepository<TEntity>
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    private readonly RemoveStrategyFactory removeStrategyFactory;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context, RemoveStrategyFactory removeStrategyFactory)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.removeStrategyFactory = removeStrategyFactory;
    }

    public void Remove(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        var entitiesToRemove = context.Set<TEntity>()
            .Where(predicate).ToList();

        var removeStrategy = removeStrategyFactory.GetStrategy<TEntity>();

        foreach (var entity in entitiesToRemove)
        {
            removeStrategy.BeforeRemove(entity);
            context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        }
    }
}

/* SAMPLE ENTITIES */

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
}

/* SAMPLE STRATEGIES and FACTORY */

public abstract class RemoveStrategy<TEntity>
{
    public abstract void BeforeRemove(TEntity entity);
}

public sealed class DoNothingRemoveStrategy<TEntity> : RemoveStrategy<TEntity>
{
    public override void BeforeRemove(TEntity entity)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

public sealed class CustomerRemoveStrategy : RemoveStrategy<Customer>
{
    public override void BeforeRemove(Customer customer)
    {
        // Mark all orders as archived
        foreach (var order in customer.Orders)
        {
            order.IsArchived = true;
        }
    }
}

public class RemoveStrategyFactory
{
    private readonly Lazy<Dictionary<Type, object>> _lazyStrategyMap;

    public RemoveStrategyFactory()
    {
        _lazyStrategyMap = new Lazy<Dictionary<Type, object>>(InitializeStrategyMap);
    }

    public RemoveStrategy<TEntity> GetStrategy<TEntity>()
    {
        var strategyMap = _lazyStrategyMap.Value;

        object strategy;

        if (strategyMap.TryGetValue(typeof(TEntity), out strategy))
        {
            return (RemoveStrategy<TEntity>) strategy;
        }

        return new DoNothingRemoveStrategy<TEntity>();
    }

    public Dictionary<Type, object> InitializeStrategyMap()
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, object>
        {
            // CAREFUL: for Customer type, it must be a RemoveStrategy<Customer> or derived instance
            { typeof (Customer), new CustomerRemoveStrategy() }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: you hit the bull's-eye. Thanks for sharing your code!